# Problem rendering image inside the amp-truncate-text tag

Tags: javascript, html, amp-html

I am having a problem with **AMP**.

I'm trying to implement a read more button, but when there are images, videos, advertisements in the **amp-truncate-text** tag, it **doesn't load the images**, it gets a loading icon, but without showing the image.

I made an example using the AMP [playground](https://playground.amp.dev/?mode=Galaxy%20S5) using the following [code](https://gist.github.com/abraaoduarte/0ae395862e3d7706fb8ba9dcc10c95d2) as an example.

Has anyone faced this problem and has any idea how I can solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

amp-trunkcate-text ist still in the experimental status. DO you have [enable the experimental status](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/experimental/)?